# Access and display value from a related model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have defined 2 models in Django (1.7). They are as follows (simplified versions):

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

class ModelA(models.Model):
    email_addr = models.EmailField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Email')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    valid_until = models.DateTimeField('valid until', default=timezone.now()+timedelta(days=2))
```

As it can be seen, there is a OneToMany relationship between the 2 models. 1 ModelA can have one or more ModelBs.

In the admin.py I have the following:

```
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'email_addr')

admin.site.register(ModelA,ModelAAdmin)
```

I would like to display in my admin a field for every record of ModelA that displays the value of the field valid_until of the latest related ModelB record. Something like:

```
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    most_recent_valid_until = // retrieve the related ModelB record with the most recent valid until value //
    list_display = ('id', 'email_addr', 'most_recent_valid_until')
```

For example, let's say:

a) there is 1 record of ModelA with the values: id:1, email_addr:foo@bar.com

b) there are 2 records of ModelB that are related to the record with id 1 of ModelA. These are the following: (id:5, valid_until:25/10/2014), (id:6, valid_until:27/10/2014).

Then, I would like my admin to display a list of records as follows:

1 foo@bar.com 27/10/2014

I am very new to Python and Django so please excuse me if my question is very obvious.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'get_valid_until')

    def get_valid_until(self, obj):
        return obj.modelb_set.last()
    get_valid_until.short_description = 'Valid until'
```

Comment: It seems to be working exactly as I wanted! Thank you very much Alex!

Answer (score 1):

`list_display` will look for properies of your ModelAdmin

```
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('id', 'email_addr', 'most_recent_valid_until')

    def most_recent_valid_until(self, obj):
      # do your query and return the data you want displayed in this row's `most_recent_valid_until` cell
```

`obj` is ModelA instance and you can query they related model b instance

If you're doing a query in calculating this property it will be doing lots of queries on your admin page...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move foreign key from ModelB to ModelA like this:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)
    email_addr = models.EmailField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Email')

class ModelB(models.Model):
    valid_until = models.DateTimeField('valid until', default=timezone.now()+timedelta(days=2))
```

and then add method to a ModelA class:

```
def valid_until():
    return self.my_model.valid_until
```

and change `list_display` to:

```
list_display = ('id', 'email_addr', 'valid_until')
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: also after moving of foreign key you can add method in ModelAAdmin like: **def valid_until(self, instance): return instance.my_model.valid_until**

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom function to list_display():

```
class ModelAAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):   
    list_display = ('id', 'email_addr', 'most_recent_valid_until')

def most_recent_valid_until(self, obj):
    return obj.modelb_set.all().order_by('-valid_until').first()
```

(untested)